# CentOS - Creating a partition for OpenVZ

Tags: centos, mount, partition

I've recently installed a fresh copy of CentOS 6.4 and I was going to install OpenVZ on it however on the install instructions it said that it is advised to make a separate EXT4 partition for the VMs.

Now I've spent around 30 minutes trying to figure out how to do this and I still don't know what to do. I don't even know how many partitions I have or if I have any free space at all.

Could someone shine some light on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install using [LVM](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/009jul05/features/lvm2/) (Logical Volume Management)? If not, you might consider re-installing now and choose to use LVM. By using this, especially with a  RHEL-based O/S, you can take advantage of the `system-config-lvm` command, which is a WYSIWYG volume manager that can be used even after the installation was completed to add/remove/re-size volumes.

Check out [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s1-system-config-lvm.html) and see if it doesn't seem much easier to do than learning the multiple ways to go about slicing the disk with primary and extended partitions manually.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, that link helped me use the manager to resize and then create another partition :)